# how to implement a swap fee or buy/sell tax on dex (eg. pancakeswap) in ERC20 Token?

Tags: erc20

is it possible to write a smart contract for ERC20 token in solidity, which implements a buy/sell tax such as 3% when buying/selling on a dex such as pancakeswap automated market maker?

say for example,
when a holder of ERC20 token goes to pancakeswap AMM and swaps his ERC20 token for USDT, a 3% tax is applied and taken from the users amount and sent to a special address.